# Copy data to other workbook based on criteria using For loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have written this code. What this code is doing. It looks for **Yes** in **1st Column** and when **Yes** is found it copies the values starting from **Column 2** in that row means **row 15**  step by step uptill column I to some other workbook and then It is supposed to go to next row where next yes is present means in my case its Row 17 but unfortunately it is not going. As I have used for loop so what I want that after it copies the values from Row 15 it will go next Yes means Row 17 but unfortunately it’s not going.

1. Find Yes. In my case First Yes is in Row 15.
2. Copies value starting from next column to some other workbook.
3. Then after completing all values in Row 15 it moves to next Yes.
4. Next Yes in my case is in Row 17 but it should be in any row so that's why I used For loop for this.

Can someone let me know where I am wrong?

Also have a look at the picture

```
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim Percent As Variant
   Dim Search As String
   Dim wkb As Workbook
   Dim WrkSht As Worksheet

     Search = InputBox("Enter your search word here")
     If Search = "" Then Exit Sub
     For i = 1 To Range("A65536").Cells.End(xlUp).Row
     If Cells(i, 1) = Search Then GoTo Other
     Next i
     MsgBox "Not avaiable"
     Exit Sub
    Other:
    For i = 1 To Range("A65536").Cells.End(xlUp).Row
     If Cells(i, 1) = Search Then

        Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        Worksheets("Template").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
        wb.Activate
        wb.SaveAs "U:\test1.xlsx"

        Workbooks("Mappe.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate


        Cells(i, 2).Select


    Workbooks("Mappe.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Copy

   Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Template").Activate
    Cells(16, 3).Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste

  Workbooks("Mappe.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Copy
  Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Template").Activate
  Cells(17, 3).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste

  Workbooks("Mappe.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Copy
  Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Template").Activate
  Cells(18, 3).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste

  Workbooks("Mappe.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Copy
  Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Template").Activate
  Cells(19, 3).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Workbooks("Mappe.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6).Copy
  Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Template").Activate
  Cells(20, 3).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Workbooks("Mappe.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Copy
  Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Template").Activate
  Cells(21, 3).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Workbooks("Mappe.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 8).Copy
  Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Template").Activate
  Cells(22, 3).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Workbooks("Mappe.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9).Copy
  Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Template").Activate
  Cells(23, 3).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste

   Workbooks("Mappe.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Copy

   Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Template").Activate
   Cells(16, 4).Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
    Workbooks("Mappe.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Copy
    Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Template").Activate
    Cells(17, 4).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Workbooks("Mappe.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Copy
    Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Template").Activate
    Cells(18, 4).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Workbooks("Mappe.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Copy
    Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Template").Activate
    Cells(19, 4).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Workbooks("Mappe.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6).Copy
    Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Template").Activate
    Cells(20, 4).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Workbooks("Mappe.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Copy
    Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Template").Activate
    Cells(21, 4).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Workbooks("Mappe.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 8).Copy
    Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Template").Activate
    Cells(22, 4).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Workbooks("Mappe.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9).Copy
    Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Template").Activate
    Cells(23, 4).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

   End If
   Next i
```

[image: Pictural Explanation of problem]

[image: Values in new formed sheets]

Comment: Where is `Suche` defined and what does it hold when called in `If Cells(i, 1) = Suche Then`?

Comment: Suche means search sorry I didn't changed the language

Comment: Now have a look at code please ..

Comment: If Cells(i, 1) = Search means if it is yes the goto Other

Comment: any suggestions please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sub should determine the used rows of the active sheet, loop through the used rows and if the first column of a row is `yes` then it creates a new workbook, copies the `template` from the active workbook and copies column 2 to column `I` into that template (in the new workbook). Then it saves the new workbook and closes it. Afterwards it loops into the next row.

This should be a good start for you to extend on your own.

```
Option Explicit 'Forces you to declare every variable

Sub testNew()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'better: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("your-worksheet-name")

    Dim NewWb As Workbook

    Dim FirstUsedRow As Long, LastUsedRow As Long
    FirstUsedRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows(1).Row 'find first used row
    LastUsedRow = FirstUsedRow + ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1 'find last used row

    Dim SearchWord As String
    SearchWord = InputBox("Enter your search word here", "Search", "yes")
    If SearchWord = "" Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'deactivate screen updating (prevents flickering)

    Dim i As Long, PasteRow As Long
    PasteRow = 1 'start pasting in row 1 of the new sheet
    For i = FirstUsedRow To LastUsedRow 'loop through all used rows
        If ws.Cells(i, 1) = SearchWord Then 'if the first column is "yes" then do ...
            If NewWb Is Nothing Then
                Set NewWb = Application.Workbooks.Add  'create a new workbook if none was created yet
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Copy Before:=NewWb.Sheets(1) 'copy sheet template into new workbook
                ThisWorkbook.Activate
            End If

            ws.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, "I")).Copy 'copy row i column 2 to column I
            NewWb.Worksheets("Template").Cells(PasteRow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
               '---> paste to new workbook sheet template at row PasteRow 

            PasteRow = PasteRow + 1 'increment to next row
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'don't forget to re-activate screen updating

    If Not NewWb Is Nothing Then 'if search word was found then save workbook
        NewWb.Activate
        NewWb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Temp\test1.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook 'save workbook
            'for FileFormat see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx
        'NewWb.Close 'close the workbook (uncomment to close the workbook)
        Set NewWb = Nothing 'empty variable
    Else
        MsgBox "Search word '" & SearchWord & "' not found."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Peh for your goodwill gesture and time. Just give me sometime I will have a look at the code and come back if there are questions.

Comment: Updated the code and added the InputBox and fixed an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peh . Your code is working very smoothly. Great.

Comment: Just one more questions if I want to copy that the values for Row 15, 17 that are copied in a new sheet every time our code finds yes but is there any possibility that we are able to perform it in 1 sheet Like Row 15 values should be copies at Range (“A1”). Row 17 values at Range (“B1”) and so on in every Next I because with this code every time we need to save the files manually.

Comment: Apart from this everything else is working perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Just to understand you correctly you want Row 15 -> column A, 17 -> column B, … in column C, …? And all in one sheet so the result is one file only?

Comment: Row 15 is copies in new sheet stating from Row (*A1-J1*).
Row17 is copied in new sheet stating from Row (*B1-J1*).
Next Row with yes is copied in new sheet starting from Row (*C1-J1*)
And so on. In this way we will be able to get all the result in 1 sheet and then we will save it.

Comment: I hope I remained able to clarify you .Thanks a lot again man for your time and help.

Comment: 1 sheet means the new sheet (Sheet 1 of Template that is created when we found yes) where our values are getting copied because with this code I am getting values but for every new yes I have to save the previous sheet with some new name .

Comment: Thanks a lot Peh for your time and help. Its great and working very smoothly.

Comment: One last thing if possible for you please have a look at that Sorry for taking your time again.
Actually my proper aim is when my code searches Yes it generates new workbook which contains Template sheet means new Sheet like template and copy Values from Rows 15,17 etc. where we find Yes to that Template sheet.

Comment: Is it possible that we copy all the values to 1 single sheet means Template sheet because the code you provided makes new sheet in workbook for every Row like Row 15 there is a new sheet and values are copied there and for Row 17 there is new sheet with copied values there.

Comment: If it is possible for you then it will be nice if you modify the code according to this.Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at picture I have uploaded another picture for clarity.Thanks a lot.

Comment: see updated code (by the way you should learn from this and give yourself a try)

Comment: Thanks a lot for help Peh . This worked perfect and great learning experience for me and I am learning it as I am not good at VBA sorry for that.